# How do I make an image load in div before thumbnail is clicked?

Tags: html, css, image

I've followed [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/click-thumbnail-and-make-it-larger-image-image-gallery-wo-javascript/) on making a clickable thumbnail to larger image div using radio labels.

What I'd like to know is whether it is possible to make a default large image appear in the div before a thumbnail is clicked.
Right now I have everything as I want, except for the fact that when I open the modal popup the div is in, the large image does not appear until a thumbnail is clicked... Searched for two nights and can't find anything helpful, hence this question.

Edit: Added link to site in question - bit of a hurried bodge for a friend, so please excuse my code! http://badsekta.com/trix/shop.html

Edit: Added more code examples to aid diagnostic.
The following code seems to work fine (at least in Firefox) in isolation, so is anyone aware of any common conflicts that might be stopping this from working in situ? I can post more code if needed, but trying not to fill this up completely!

CSS >

```
/* CSS only gallery (using radio inputs)
 * See http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/click-thumbnail-and-make-it-larger-image-image-gallery-wo-javascript/
 * Support needed for IE7 & older - see http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/
 */
#column1-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
#column1 {
    width: 360px;
    text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    }
.wrapper .thumbnails {
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 385px;
}
.wrapper a {
    margin: 2px;
}
.wrapper img {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}
.wrapper img:hover {
    border: 3px solid #F00;
}
.wrapper label > img {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.wrapper label > img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.wrapper input {
    display: none;
}
.wrapper input:checked + .full-image {
    display: block;
}
.wrapper input:checked ~ img {
 opacity: 1;
}
.wrapper .full-image {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML >

```
<div id="column1-wrap">
      <div id="column1">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="full-image" ></div>
          <div class="thumbnails">
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="full-image" checked>
            <div class="full-image"> <img src="http://picbook.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/happy_diwali__sms_images_.jpg" width="340" height="365"  /> </div>
            <img src="http://picbook.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/happy_diwali__sms_images_.jpg" width="69" height="73" />
            </label>
            &nbsp;
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="full-image">
            <div class="full-image"> <img src="http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--OpFMWJzB--/199vu342jcfpwjpg.jpg" width="340" height="365" /> </div>
            <img src="http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--OpFMWJzB--/199vu342jcfpwjpg.jpg" width="69" height="73" />
            </label>
            &nbsp;
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="full-image">
            <div class="full-image"> <img src="assets/img/shop-images/orchid-girl-knickers-3.jpg" width="340" height="365" /> </div>
            <img src="assets/img/shop-images/orchid-girl-knickers-3.jpg" width="69" height="73" />
            </label>
            &nbsp;
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="full-image">
            <div class="full-image"> <img src="assets/img/shop-images/orchid-girl-knickers-4.jpg" width="340" height="365"  /> </div>
            <img src="assets/img/shop-images/orchid-girl-knickers-4.jpg" width="63" height="73"/>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's definitely possible.  But it's difficult to help you unless you provide some of your code.

Comment: Thanks Waxen - added link now.

Answer (score 1):

Look for

```
<input type="radio" name="full-image" checked>
```

remove checked and use it within your default image code.

Make sure to put your code at the top after

```
<div class="thumbnails">
```

That's how the result should be:

```
  <label>
<input type="radio" name="full-image" checked>
<div class="full-image">
    <img src="your image link/location">
</div>
</label>
```

Check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oswGy) example that I've made.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nora, but I'm still a little confused, as I can't spot the differences around the 'checked' items. Perhaps the link I've now posted might help? This kind of thing is a new area for me, so your assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: I copied and pasted from [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/click-thumbnail-and-make-it-larger-image-image-gallery-wo-javascript/), but looks the same - any further ideas why it's not working? :-) Thank you!

Comment: It's supposed to work; I've tried it on the same code. What did you exactly do? Did you just remove 'checked'? You're welcome!

Comment: It's odd, I've added the specific code to Codepen now myself and it works fine (please see edit to original question for that code) - I don't suppose you're aware of anything 'common' I can look for that might cause some kind of conflict? Kind of feeling my way here! Have a good weekend...